# Continuously adding SSH key to the ssh-agent

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ssh-agent

Under OS X 10.9.5, I am constantly hitting the `git exit status: 128` error because of `Permission denied (public key)`.

The key is verifiably on the version control system, but every time I **change** applications I need to:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to get a deployment process working.

While not very cumbersome, it is a sign of some bad configuration which may be leading to other permissions issues.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "change" applications? Do you mean that you are deploying different apps and each time you move between app directories in the same terminal, you have to run `ssh-add` again?

Comment: I have multiple application that deploy.  Each is a directory. So, you guessed it correct, when I change directory, I have been  forced to run the add key to the ssh agent command

Comment: Odd. The same key each time?

Comment: Yes.  Four applications, one initialization, four switches (the last back to the initial application!).   Switched just now to another app and same error. behaviour confirming itself repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following described in the Github docs page [Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent):

> *If you're using macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later, you will need to modify your ~/.ssh/config file to automatically load keys into the ssh-agent and store passphrases in your keychain.*

So either create or edit `~/.ssh/config`, and add:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_id
```

This way you don't need an additional package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation that has helped me debug SSH-Agent issues in the past: https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

Adding the verbose flag to SSH has helped me fix a number of issues.

Also, try this: https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor

Other than that, I'm not sure I can hazard an answer to this. Good luck!

Comment: I think I just intercepted the behaviour.  I just changed a capistrano setting `Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)`.  Running a migration just after that, I hit the problem. an `ssh-add` and the deploy would function anew...